# MetaPost graph: how can we make setrange to accept negative coordinates (when numbersystem is not scale)?

Tags: graphs, metapost

I want to plot graph with the MetaPost package `graph`.
I have just noticed that `setrange` does not accept negative coordinates
when `-numbersystem` is not `scale`.

More precisely, it takes their absolute value instead, so that `setrange(-4,0,11,100)` is actually taken as `setrange(4,0,11,100)`.

Does any one know a way to fix this issue ?

The example below reproduces the error.

```
outputformat:="eps";
prologues:=3;
input graph
outputtemplate:="figure-01.eps";
beginfig(1);
Width:=7cm;
    draw begingraph(Width,0.618034*Width);
        setrange(-4,0,+11,100);
        gdraw "setrange.data";
    endgraph;
endfig;
bye;
```

with as data file `setrange.data`

```
-10 100
-9 81
-8 64
-7 49
-6 36
-5 25
-4 16
-3 9
-2 4
-1 1
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that shows how to draw such a graph?

Comment: `setrange` certainly does support negative numbers.  Can you please post a *complete* minimal example that shows the problem?  You might find that the axis *labels* don't exactly respect your range, for example it might only label even numbers.  But the actual size of the axis will follow what you set.

Comment: that looks like a bug with the new number systems.  As a work around, use the default number system.   `graph` will automatically attempt to use `sarith` with large numbers...

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a bug with the new number systems.  In particular it appears that parts of `marith.mp` will only work when `numbersystem=scaled`.

So the way to fix this is (at least for now) is to stick to the default number system when you use `graph.mp`.